# R interval between consecutive events meeting condition - data.table way

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset of consecutive events, grouped by an id and sorted by event start date (start). Each event can have 2 states (cond), a and b. I need to calculate the interval between 2 CONSECUTIVE events (start -end), but only if the newer event meets a certain criterion: cond !="b". If not, interval=NA for that event and move to the next one. Here's a toy dataset:

```
dt=data.table(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
      id = c(111, 111, 111, 111, 222, 222, 222, 222, 333, 333, 333, 333),
    cond=c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
   start = c(as.Date( "11/19/2020", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "11/27/2020", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "12/5/2020", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "12/13/2020", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "12/21/2020", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "12/29/2020", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "1/6/2021", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "1/14/2021", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "1/22/2021", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "1/30/2021", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "2/7/2021", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "2/15/2021", format="%m/%d/%Y")),
     end = c(as.Date( "11/24/2020", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "12/2/2020", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "12/10/2020", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "12/18/2020", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "12/26/2020", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "1/3/2021", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "1/11/2021", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "1/19/2021", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "1/27/2021", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "2/4/2021", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "2/12/2021", format="%m/%d/%Y"),as.Date( "2/20/2021", format="%m/%d/%Y")
))
```

The result should look like this:

```
    id cond      start        end interval
1  111    a 11/19/2020 11/24/2020        3
2  111    a 11/27/2020  12/2/2020        3
3  111    a  12/5/2020 12/10/2020        3
4  111    a 12/13/2020 12/18/2020       NA
5  222    a 12/21/2020 12/26/2020       NA
6  222    b 12/29/2020   1/3/2021        3
7  222    a   1/6/2021  1/11/2021        3
8  222    a  1/14/2021  1/19/2021       NA
9  333    a  1/22/2021  1/27/2021       NA
10 333    b  1/30/2021   2/4/2021       NA
11 333    b   2/7/2021  2/12/2021       NA
12 333    b  2/15/2021  2/20/2021       NA
```

So, the condition cond!="b" applies only to the "start" row; i would have hoped that something like this would work:

```
dt[,interval:= shift(start[cond!="b"],n = 1L,type="lead") -end ,id]
```

but it doesn't. I've also tried a rolling join:

```
dt[,row_id:=rowid(id)]
dt[, interval := 
     .SD[.(cond!="b", id = id, row_id = row_id +1), on=.(id,row_id), roll=-Inf, x.start]-end]
```

which doesn't do what i need either. I feel that data.table should be able to handle this task pretty easily. i just can't figure out how. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Result is not clear to me. How is interval = 3 in 1st row? 24-19 should be 5. Why is row 4 `NA` ?

Comment: start (row n+1) -end (row n). For example, 11/27/2020 - 11/24/2020 = 3 days. Row 4 is NA because there are no more events for the id=111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `interval` value you can subtract the next `start` date from `end` date for each `id`. Turn all the `interval` values to `NA` where the next value in `cond` is `'b'`.

```
library(data.table)

dt[, interval := as.integer(shift(start, type = 'lead') - end), id]
dt[shift(cond, type = 'lead') == 'b', interval := NA]
dt

#     id cond      start        end interval
# 1: 111    a 2020-11-19 2020-11-24        3
# 2: 111    a 2020-11-27 2020-12-02        3
# 3: 111    a 2020-12-05 2020-12-10        3
# 4: 111    a 2020-12-13 2020-12-18       NA
# 5: 222    a 2020-12-21 2020-12-26       NA
# 6: 222    b 2020-12-29 2021-01-03        3
# 7: 222    a 2021-01-06 2021-01-11        3
# 8: 222    a 2021-01-14 2021-01-19       NA
# 9: 333    a 2021-01-22 2021-01-27       NA
#10: 333    b 2021-01-30 2021-02-04       NA
#11: 333    b 2021-02-07 2021-02-12       NA
#12: 333    b 2021-02-15 2021-02-20       NA
```